# I need to set a limit to the number of rules that appear in my apriori

Tags: r, apriori, arules

```
rules = apriori(PV_m, parameter = list(supp = 0.91, conf = 0.91, target = "rules"))
```

I have already tried playing around with `supp` and `conf` to limit the amount of rules that come but it goes from 4 rules to 142 rules in a 0.00001 interval

IF NO ANSWER: do you know how to set a limit to the amount of categories that can appear in the LHS and the RHS to 1

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you want to mine 1000s of rules and then sort them by a measure of interestingness (e.g., lift). You could use the top x rules from this list, where x is the number of rules you want.

Use `maxlen` in the `parameter` list to limit the number of items in the LHS and RHS (see `? APparameter`).